# How to create entry inputs in a toplevel window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i have a problem and can't get my head around it. How to create a child window on pressing a button using tkinter in python were I can entry values like for example:

```
import tkinter
root = Tk()
Button(root, text='Bring up Message', command=Window).pack()
root.mainloop()

def messageWindow():
win = Toplevel()
-------->calculate------
Label(win, text=message).pack()
Button(win, text='OK', command=win.destroy).pack()
```

and on the message window i would like to have two entry fields were I can enter a and b and afterwards it should calc a+b and give me the result.

Thank you.

Comment: Please narrow down a question.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use `from tkinter import *` since there isn't a `tkinter.` preceding the module's classes used in your script.

Also, is your "Bring up Message" button supposed to call the `messageWindow()` function? Right now it's calling an undefined function `Window`. If so, you should change the `Button's` command and move your `messageWindow()` function above the line where you created the button or else it will call the function before it is defined and generate an error.

The syntax of an `Entry` widget in Tkinter goes as follows:

```
entry = Entry(root, *options)
entry.pack()
```

You need to `pack()` the entry widget after you define it. You won't be able to retrieve the input inside it if you `pack()` it on the same line as you define it as it will become a `NoneType` object.

You will need at least two `Entry` widgets, one to enter input `a` and one to enter input `b`.

You can also add a third `Entry` to print the result of the sum of `a` and `b` to, though you can use a label or just print it to the console.

```
entry_a = Entry(win)
entry_a.pack()

entry_b = Entry(win)
entry_b.pack()

# Optional answer entry
entry_ans = Entry(win)
entry_ans.pack()
```

You should then create a function (still within the `messageWindow()` function) that will retrieve the input from the two entries and add them, as well as another `Button` to call that function. I implemented some additional error-checking in the form of a try-except for when the entries are blank or contain something other than integers:

```
def add():
    try:
        a = int(entry_a.get())
        b = int(entry_b.get())
        ab_sum = a + b

        # Optional printing to answer entry
        entry_ans.delete(0, 'end')
        entry_ans.insert(0, ab_sum)
    except:
        pass      

Button(win, text="Add", command=add).pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"How to create entry inputs in a toplevel window"*

```
import tkinter as tk
...
toplevel = tk.Toplevel(...)
tk.Entry(toplevel)
```

---

> *"How to create a child window on pressing a button..."*

```
import tkinter as tk
...
def create_child_window(widget):
    tk.Toplevel(widget)

...
root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, command=lambda w = root: create_child_window(w))
```